# Image upload to Temp Folder warning

Tags: php

From the script below, can anyone tell me what I've done wrong to get the warning message on output of the script? The upload script is -

**Code:**

```
<?php
// Access the $_FILES global variable for this specific file being uploaded
// and create local PHP variables from the $_FILES array of information
$fileName = $_FILES["thumb"]["name"]; // The file name
$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["thumb"]["tmp_name"]; // File in the PHP tmp folder
$fileType = $_FILES["thumb"]["type"]; // The type of file it is
$fileSize = $_FILES["thumb"]["size"]; // File size in bytes
$fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["thumb"]["error"]; // 0 = false | 1 = true
$fileSplit = explode(".", $fileName); // Split file name into an array using the dot
$fileExt = end($fileSplit); // Now target the last array element to get the file extension
// START PHP Image Upload Error Handling --------------------------------------------------
if (!$fileTmpLoc) { // if file not chosen
    echo "ERROR: Please browse for a file before clicking the upload button.";
    exit();
} else if($fileSize > 5242880) { // if file size is larger than 5 Megabytes
    echo "ERROR: Your file was larger than 5 Megabytes in size.";
    unlink($fileTmpLoc); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder
    exit();
} else if (!preg_match("/.(gif|jpg|png)$/i", $fileName) ) {
     // This condition is only if you wish to allow uploading of specific file types    
     echo "ERROR: Your image was not .gif, .jpg, or .png.";
     unlink($fileTmpLoc); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder
     exit();
} else if ($fileErrorMsg == 1) { // if file upload error key is equal to 1
    echo "ERROR: An error occured while processing the file. Try again.";
    exit();
}
// END PHP Image Upload Error Handling ----------------------------------------------------
// Place it into your "Avatars" folder mow using the move_uploaded_file() function
$moveResult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "Avatars/$fileName");
// Check to make sure the move result is true before continuing
if ($moveResult != true) {
    echo "ERROR: File not uploaded. Try again.";
    unlink($fileTmpLoc); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder
    exit();
}
unlink($fileTmpLoc); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder
// Display things to the page so you can see what is happening for testing purposes
echo "The file named <strong>$fileName</strong> uploaded successfully.<br /><br />";
echo "It is <strong>$fileSize</strong> bytes in size.<br /><br />";
echo "It is an <strong>$fileType</strong> type of file.<br /><br />";
echo "The file extension is <strong>$fileExt</strong><br /><br />";
echo "The Error Message output for this upload is: $fileErrorMsg";
?>
```

---

**My form is this**

```
<?php
    $profile_pic_btn = '<a href="#" onclick="return false;" onmousedown="toggleElement(\'avatar_form\')">Toggle Avatar Form</a>';
    $avatar_form  = '<form id="avatar_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="process_reguser_exec.php">';
    $avatar_form .=   '<h4>Change your avatar</h4>';
    $avatar_form .=   '<input type="file" name="thumb">';
    $avatar_form .=   '<p><input type="submit" value="Upload"></p>';
    $avatar_form .= '</form>';
?>
```

---

**The output is this**

```
Warning: unlink(C:\xampp\tmp\php8E40.tmp): No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyWebSite\process_reguser_exec.php on line 37

The file named image1.JPG uploaded successfully.

It is 3337452 bytes in size.

It is an image/jpeg type of file.

The file extension is JPG

The Error Message output for this upload is: 0
```

---

**Line 37 is this**

```
unlink($fileTmpLoc); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have used the move_uploaded_file command, the file in the tmp location is no longer there, and therefor cannot be removed, I would say.

Looking a bit harder at your code, consider a restructuring:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "Avatars/$fileName"))
  {
  // do the image stuff
  }
else
  {
  echo "ERROR: An error occured uploading and storing your file. Please try again.";
  // Add a test to see whether the file exists
  unlink($fileTmpLoc); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder
  exit();
  }
```

Comment: Exactly. As the function name suggests, it actually **moves** the file from the tmp folder to the supplied destination. Conclusion, you do not need to worry about deleting the tmp file afterwards.

Comment: I see the logic. I removed line 37 and that seems to have resolved the problem

Answer (score 0):

The regEx that you are using here

```
preg_match("/.(gif|jpg|png)$/i", $fileName)
```

is **probably wrong**. Because it will **return true** even for this file name `$fileName="adjGIF"` and i hope that you do not want this.So instead use this

```
preg_match("/.(\.(gif|jpg|png))$/i", $fileName)
```

Note:- **Even though its not the answer but it will make your code correct.**

Answer (score 0):

use below code to move image file in to avatar named folder :

```
move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc,"Avatars".$fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

//returns TRUE if the file or directory specified by filename exists and is readable, FALSE otherwise.

```
if (is_readable($fileTmpLoc)) {
   unlink($fileTmpLoc);
}
```